# Logging out of an iframe in the microsoft teams desktop app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an app-experience that is embedded within an iframe in the team's app. The app-experience has a `logout` button which basically calls the `/logout` endpoint of my site. If that call is successful, I close the iframe using `MSTeams.submitTask()` without passing any data.

```
function logout() {
    fetch('/api/logout', {method: 'POST'})
      .then(() => MSTeams.tasks.submitTask())
```

When, I open the iframe again the cookies under my site's domain are still not unset and I am still not logged out from my app experience although if I try the same thing the MS Teams browser app, I get logged out properly.

I guess this might have to do with how the electron app handles cookies, or I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does this have to do with the Bot Framework?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry, I updated the tags. It's generally about understanding how microsoft teams behaves.

Also, if I am posting in the wrong place, please help me out here - I would love to post to the right channels if you know about it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Deepankar - Make sure your samesite attribute is set to "Strict". For more details please check and follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update#samesite-cookie-attribute-2020-release)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This did not work for me. As we want to send cookies from an iframe, I don't know how "Strict" could work as browsers would strictly omit the cookies which are marked as "Strict" and are in third party context.

What worked instead, was using `credentials: include` in fetch. This made sure that my auth cookies are sent explicitly for cross origin requests.